# For to mount json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have in variable `bookUnitIdInformacoes` this array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "book_id": 33,
    "unit": 1,
    "sequence": 1,
    "description": "UNIT_01_GRAMMAR",
    "qt_question": 5,
    "status": false,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-12-27 08:11:21",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-30 14:54:12",
    "miniature": null
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "book_id": 33,
    "unit": 1,
    "sequence": 2,
    "description": "UNIT_01_VOCABULARY",
    "qt_question": 5,
    "status": false,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-12-27 08:11:39",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-27 08:11:39",
    "miniature": null
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "book_id": 33,
    "unit": 2,
    "sequence": 1,
    "description": "UNIT_02_GRAMMAR",
    "qt_question": 5,
    "status": false,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-12-27 08:11:46",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-27 08:11:46",
    "miniature": null
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "book_id": 39,
    "unit": 1,
    "sequence": 1,
    "description": "UNIT_01_GRAMMAR",
    "qt_question": 5,
    "status": false,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-12-30 11:07:09",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-30 15:03:50",
    "miniature": null
  }
]
```

I have in the variable `idioma` this array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "code": "ING-NOT-2019",
    "description": "Inglês Noturno 2019",
    "start_date": "2019-12-30T03:00:00.000Z",
    "end_date": "2019-12-31T03:00:00.000Z",
    "period": "Noturno",
    "language": "Inglês",
    "status": false,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-12-30 10:04:47",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-05 16:08:00",
    "language_substring": "US"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "code": "ESP-MAN-2019",
    "description": "Espanhol manhã 2019",
    "start_date": "2019-12-30T03:00:00.000Z",
    "end_date": "2019-12-31T03:00:00.000Z",
    "period": "Manhã",
    "language": "Espanhol",
    "status": false,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-12-30 11:06:44",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-30 11:06:44",
    "language_substring": null
  }
]
```

I need to create a for() that while the column `book_id` is equal the index+1, insert in idioma[i].quiz the value of the `bookUnitIdInformacoes[i]` and when the book_id of the `bookUnitIdInformacoes` array is different, put in the next position of `idioma[i]quiz`, so i need this json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "code": "ING-NOT-2019",
    "description": "Inglês Noturno 2019",
    "start_date": "2019-12-30T03:00:00.000Z",
    "end_date": "2019-12-31T03:00:00.000Z",
    "period": "Noturno",
    "language": "Inglês",
    "status": false,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-12-30 10:04:47",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-05 16:08:00",
    "language_substring": "US",
    "quiz": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "book_id": 33,
        "unit": 1,
        "sequence": 1,
        "description": "UNIT_01_GRAMMAR",
        "qt_question": 5,
        "status": false,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-12-27 08:11:21",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-30 14:54:12",
        "miniature": null
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "book_id": 33,
        "unit": 1,
        "sequence": 2,
        "description": "UNIT_01_VOCABULARY",
        "qt_question": 5,
        "status": false,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-12-27 08:11:39",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-27 08:11:39",
        "miniature": null
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "book_id": 33,
        "unit": 2,
        "sequence": 1,
        "description": "UNIT_02_GRAMMAR",
        "qt_question": 5,
        "status": false,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-12-27 08:11:46",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-27 08:11:46",
        "miniature": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "code": "ESP-MAN-2019",
    "description": "Espanhol manhã 2019",
    "start_date": "2019-12-30T03:00:00.000Z",
    "end_date": "2019-12-31T03:00:00.000Z",
    "period": "Manhã",
    "language": "Espanhol",
    "status": false,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-12-30 11:06:44",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-30 11:06:44",
    "language_substring": null,
    "quiz": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "book_id": 39,
        "unit": 1,
        "sequence": 1,
        "description": "UNIT_01_GRAMMAR",
        "qt_question": 5,
        "status": false,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-12-30 11:07:09",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-30 15:03:50",
        "miniature": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I try something like:

```
  for(let i=0;i<quizAbertos.length;i++){
        if(i+1 === quizAbertos.length){
            break;
        }else{
    if(bookUnitIdInformacoes[i].book_id === bookUnitIdInformacoes[i+1].book_id){
        idioma[i].quiz = bookUnitIdInformacoes[i]
    }
  }
```

But i'm getting wrong json..

@Edit:

Actually i'm trying something like:

```
 let book_id
  let i_book_id = 0
  let i_mudou_book_id = 0;

  for(let i=0;i<bookUnitIdInformacoes.length;i++){
   if(bookUnitIdInformacoes[i+1] === undefined){
    book_id = bookUnitIdInformacoes[bookUnitIdInformacoes.length-1].book_id
   }else{
    if(bookUnitIdInformacoes[i].book_id === bookUnitIdInformacoes[i+1].book_id){
     i_mudou_book_id++
    }
   }
  }


   idioma[0].quiz = bookUnitIdInformacoes.splice(0,i_mudou_book_id+1)
   idioma[1].quiz = bookUnitIdInformacoes
```

but this way if i have more than 2 length i will be have problems and if i have only one length i will be too have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can group the `bookUnitIdInfomacoes` by `book_id`. This can be done by reducing the array into an object of `key => value` pairs as `book_id => array of books`:

```
{
  "33": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "book_id": 33,
      ...
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "book_id": 33,
      ...
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "book_id": 33,
      ...
    }
  ],
  "39": [
    {
      "id": 8,
      "book_id": 39,
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) will allow us to retrieve only the values of this `groupedObj` object. This will give us:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "book_id": 33,
      ...
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "book_id": 33,
      ...
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "book_id": 33,
      ...
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 8,
      "book_id": 39,
      ...
    }
  ]
]
```

Lastly, we will have to map `idiomas` and add the corresponding book group into a new property called `quizz`. For a given `idioma`, we know its position in `idiomas` thanks to the second argument of `map`: `i`. We can simply do `grouped[i]` to get the corresponding group of books.

```js
const groupedObj = bookUnitIdInformacoes.reduce((grouped, info) => {
  grouped[info.book_id] = grouped[info.book_id] || [];
  grouped[info.book_id].push(info);
  return grouped;
}, {});

const grouped = Object.values(groupedObj);

const result = idiomas.map((idioma, i) => ({
  ...idioma,
  quizz: grouped[i]
}));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>const bookUnitIdInformacoes=[{id:5,book_id:33,unit:1,sequence:1,description:"UNIT_01_GRAMMAR",qt_question:5,status:!1,user_id:1,created_at:"2019-12-27 08:11:21",updated_at:"2019-12-30 14:54:12",miniature:null},{id:6,book_id:33,unit:1,sequence:2,description:"UNIT_01_VOCABULARY",qt_question:5,status:!1,user_id:1,created_at:"2019-12-27 08:11:39",updated_at:"2019-12-27 08:11:39",miniature:null},{id:7,book_id:33,unit:2,sequence:1,description:"UNIT_02_GRAMMAR",qt_question:5,status:!1,user_id:1,created_at:"2019-12-27 08:11:46",updated_at:"2019-12-27 08:11:46",miniature:null},{id:8,book_id:39,unit:1,sequence:1,description:"UNIT_01_GRAMMAR",qt_question:5,status:!1,user_id:1,created_at:"2019-12-30 11:07:09",updated_at:"2019-12-30 15:03:50",miniature:null}],idiomas=[{id:13,code:"ING-NOT-2019",description:"Inglês Noturno 2019",start_date:"2019-12-30T03:00:00.000Z",end_date:"2019-12-31T03:00:00.000Z",period:"Noturno",language:"Inglês",status:!1,user_id:1,created_at:"2019-12-30 10:04:47",updated_at:"2020-01-05 16:08:00",language_substring:"US"},{id:14,code:"ESP-MAN-2019",description:"Espanhol manhã 2019",start_date:"2019-12-30T03:00:00.000Z",end_date:"2019-12-31T03:00:00.000Z",period:"Manhã",language:"Espanhol",status:!1,user_id:1,created_at:"2019-12-30 11:06:44",updated_at:"2019-12-30 11:06:44",language_substring:null}];</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need. i only change "idiomas" to "idioma", because is the name of my array, but anyway thanks

Comment: is not working for me now, the idioma.id -1 not always will be equal to the bookUnitIdInformacoes .book_id

Comment: @veroneseWithS, what do you mean by that? Can you give an example where what you described might occur?

Comment: if i have idiomas[0].id = 5 by example, this code don't work. Idiomas.id not always will be equal the bookUnitIdInformacoes.book_id.

I need to check while book_id is equal the next position, put the array in first position of idioma.quiz, if is don't equal (book_id= 1 <> book_id=2) put the array in the last position of idioma.quiz, i be clear?

Comment: note: for each book_id that have different value, i have one idioma[i] to put inside

Comment: @veroneseWithS, it is not really clear to me how this works. You should add in your original post an entry in the array where this happens. It will help me figure out the solution.

Comment: i need to group equals book_id and put in idioma.quiz, the length of this group will be exactly the length of the idioma array. so i need to put the first position of this group in idioma[0] and the last position of this group in idioma[1]. The entry is two querys that result the array that i put on the question

Comment: @veroneseWithS, I'm afraid I don't understand what you're looking for. As far as I can tell the code above provides the desired result. Please *edit* your original post with "an idioma's id not equal to `bookUnitIdInformacoes.book_id`".

Comment: thanks but the book_id can be different of the index+1 :(

Comment: @veroneseWithS Again, your example doesn't show this. The code gives the result you wanted in your question. *Please edit your post with a complete example that covers all cases!*

Comment: sorry i'm trying to do my best. I updated my question and inserted my last code that i almost do what i need

Comment: @veroneseWithS, do you want to group all `bookUnitIdInformacoes` that have the same `book_id` inside `idioma.quizz`es orderly?

Comment: yes, in this case, i have two group and two idioma, i need to put in each idioma the group, the first group needs to be inside the first idioma.quiz, and the second group needs to be inside the second idioma.quiz

Comment: @veroneseWithS, I've updated my answer, hopefully this is the one!

Comment: Thanks, i think now it's all i need. when i do a console.log(return) i think i'm receiving a serialized vanilla json, but i will try to fix this, thanks